# Rund grunt task from node and keep result in variable

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I would like to run a grunt task from a node .js file, sync.

Its a build process so all scripts/tasks that fail should halt the build.

I tried just

```
var res = grunt.tasks(['compile']);
console.log('res: ', res);
```

and that runs my compile task but nothing is stored in `res`. Actually i see that the task is ran `async` since the log appears before the task even started.

**How can I do this?**

btw, tried also

```
grunt.util.spawn({
    grunt: true,
    args: ['compile']
}, function(err, res, code) {
    console.log('err', err);
});
```

but that didn't give any output, just blocked my command line...

Answer (score 0):

`// If specified, the same grunt bin that is currently running will be
// spawned as the child command, instead of the "cmd" option.`

What I read here is that the `spawn` snippet is supposed to be run with `grunt`, not with `node` directly, as the question 's title implies.

Comment: Hmm ok, I see. So is there another way I can run a grunt task from inside a `.js`, sync and store its result in a variable?

Comment: @Rikard Yes, run it as a shell command like you would with any other program and grab its output/error.